# How to tell the CosmosDB API flavor looking at the CosmosDB account

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We have 100s of CosmosDB Accounts in our Org. Looking at the CosmosDB account, I would like to know what API flavor of CosmosDB is it coz I need to change my next commands based on API flavor.

6 flavors: NoSQL  MongoDB  Cassandra  Gremlin  Table  PostgreSQL

Get-AzCosmosDBAccount -ResourceGroupName MyResourceGroupName
is giving me details but not giving me which of 6 API flavor the CosmosDB belongs to

Comment: Does the `Kind` element [in the result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/get-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-9.2.0#example-1) indicate this? I'm not in a position to test and don't see any documentation about what that returns? Looks like it may well correspond to the `ApiKind` from `New-AzCosmosDBAccount` though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.cosmosdb/new-azcosmosdbaccount?view=azps-9.2.0#-apikind

Comment: Nope, the Kind can be anything. If you don't specify the Kind while creation, it is taking default value which is GlobalDocumentDB. I see Tags are getting created as per the PI flavor. But not consistent either. Tags for Table flavor is empty.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, I just created all 6 API flavors in my test subscription. the Kind is not matching to API flavor. only "**EnabledApiTypes**" is matching accurately.

ResourceName: ramp-apache-casssandra | EnabledApiTypes: Cassandra | Kind: GlobalDocumentDB

ResourceName: ramp-mongodb | EnabledApiTypes: MongoDB | Kind: MongoDB

ResourceName: ramp-nosql | EnabledApiTypes: Sql | Kind: GlobalDocumentDB

ResourceName: ramp-apache-gremlin | EnabledApiTypes: Gremlin, Sql | Kind: GlobalDocumentDB

ResourceName: ramp-table | EnabledApiTypes: Table, Sql | Kind: GlobalDocumentDB

Comment: I have no idea what EnabledAPITypes is. The object returned by this command is PSDatabaseAccount. If you look at the source code for this object there is no EnabledAPITypes property. https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/blob/main/src/CosmosDB/CosmosDB/Models/DatabaseAccount/PSDatabaseAccountGetResults.cs#L26

Comment: I used below RestAPI Call

GET https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000/resourceGroups/MtResourceGroupName/providers/Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts?api-version=2022-08-15-preview HTTP/1.1

Comment: I thought the question was regarding PowerShell. In either case EnabledApiTypes appears nowhere in our swagger so still unclear where you are getting this. https://github.com/Azure/azure-rest-api-specs/blob/main/specification/cosmos-db/resource-manager/Microsoft.DocumentDB/preview/2022-08-15-preview/cosmos-db.json  One other comment is you should use stable versions for the RP REST API as Preview versions will often change. Latest api version is 2022-08-15.

Answer (score 3):

The database api for a Cosmos DB account is set and read with a combination of the Kind property and the Capabilities array. This is the mapping for them. Note that Capabilities is an array. You may need to iterate through it to find the values below.

NoSQL API:

```
Kind = GlobalDocumentDB
```

MongoDB API:

```
Kind = MongoDB
```

Gremlin API:

```
Kind = GlobalDocumentDB, Capabilities = "EnableGremlin"
```

Cassandra API:

```
Kind = GlobalDocumentDB, Capabilities = "EnableCassadra"
```

Table API:

```
Kind = GlobalDocumentDB, Capabilities = "EnableTable"
```

The PostgreSQL API is on a different resource provider which is still in Preview. Currently there aren't any PS cmdlets for it.

Edit: have added the output from this command on a Cassandra account.[image]

Comment: Actually, I just created all 6 API flavors in my test subscription. the Kind is not matching to API flavor. only "EnabledApiTypes" is matching accurately.

ResourceName: ramp-apache-casssandra | EnabledApiTypes: Cassandra | Kind: GlobalDocumentDB
ResourceName: ramp-mongodb | EnabledApiTypes: MongoDB | Kind: MongoDB
ResourceName: ramp-nosql | EnabledApiTypes: Sql | Kind: GlobalDocumentDB
ResourceName: ramp-apache-gremlin | EnabledApiTypes: Gremlin, Sql | Kind: GlobalDocumentDB
ResourceName: ramp-table | EnabledApiTypes: Table, Sql | Kind: GlobalDocumentDB